# How to no change the address by clicking the menu button. Swap only one component on screen?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to Reactjs and am developing a base menu. I wish that when I clicked on a menu option the page would not update, just change the part outside the menu.

Comment: please provide some code examples?

Comment: Please take some time to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Stack Overflow is quite different from forums and other online Q&A sites in the expectation that askers put much more effort into bringing a complete, answerable question.